# eSpeak to mp3 in php on both windows and linux (online text-to-speech)

Tags: php, linux, windows, text-to-speech, espeak

I want to implement simple text-to-speech script in my web application that would dynamically generate mp3's out of given texts.

It needs to run in both:

- my local WAMP server on windows
- and my online linux server

eSpeak doesn't offer the highest quality in sound but at least a strong support in languages, simple implementation and also it's free. So after a little digging i realized there are not much examples of integrating it into php. I concluded StackOverflow should contain a simple implementation of a php text to speech script that generates mp3 with eSpeak and lame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to setup path to espeak and lame. Make sure you have installed both. In my case it looks like this:

I tought, someone might find this useful. I'm using this code to generate my command in local windows wamp server and online linux server:

```
// APPLICATION PATHS AND CONFIG
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
    //This is a server using Windows!
    define('ESPEAK', '..\application\libraries\espeak-win\command_line\espeak');
    define('LAME', '..\application\libraries\espeak-win\command_line\lame');
} 
else {
    //This is a server not using Windows!
    define('ESPEAK', '/usr/bin/espeak');
    define('LAME', '/usr/bin/lame');
}
```

Then, write your own command to be executed. I used %s spots to be replaced later with desired values. [List of espeak commands can be found here](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/commands.html).

In case you **don't need mp3 conversion** and you are satisfied with .wav files, just remove the part after `|` (including this character) and replace argument `--stdout` with this two args `-w desired_file_path`. In that case make sure to correctly set %s variables later on.

```
define('COMMAND', ESPEAK.' --stdout -v %s+m3 -p 60 -a 75 -s 130 "%s" | '.LAME.' --preset voice -q 9 --vbr-new - %s');
```

and then execute the script like this:

```
$lang_voice = 'en';
$input_text = 'some input text to read';
$file_path = 'voice-cache/output.mp3'
$exe_path = sprintf(COMMAND, $lang_voice, $input_text, $file_path); // fills %s spots
exec($exe_path);
```

As a last step, just output generated file:

```
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_path));
readfile($file_path);
```

Comment: Is there a way to not to generate the file but just to play it?

Comment: @lewis4uI You might try to save the file to the buffer and serve directly to the client the same way you would generate a file download on the fly. But I would not recommend this due to performance issues and then you are unabled to cache a file.